# How to convert number to words - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a very simple query which result a value 500, i need to convert this value like following:-

```
old value =     500

new value =  FIVE HUNDERED/=
```

Comment: If we do your homework, will you learn anything at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the force Luke ;)

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7749/0)**

```
SELECT UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(500,'J'),'Jsp')) || '/=' AS new_value
FROM dual;
```

The clue is `Date` in spelled format.

**EDIT:**

Adding support for `negative numbers`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7757/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 10 AS num      FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT -500 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 0    FROM dual
)
SELECT num AS old_value,
       decode( sign( num ), -1, 'NEGATIVE ', 0, 'ZERO', NULL ) ||
       decode( sign( abs(num) ), +1, to_char( to_date( abs(num),'J'),'JSP') ) || '/=' AS new_value
FROM cte
```

### EDIT 2:##

Adding limited support for float:

**[SqlFiddleDemo3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7774/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 10 AS num       FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT -500  FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 0     FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 10.3  FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT -10.7 FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  num AS old_value,
  decode( sign( num ), -1, 'NEGATIVE ', 0, 'ZERO', NULL )
  || decode( sign( abs(num) ), +1, to_char( to_date( abs(TRUNC(num)),'J'),'JSP') )
  ||
  CASE
     WHEN INSTR (num, '.') > 0
     THEN  ' POINT ' || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(num, INSTR (num, '.') + 1)),'J'),'JSP')
     ELSE NULL
  END AS new_value
FROM cte
```

---

**EDIT 3:**

> for 10.3 output is TEN POINT THREE but it should be TEN POINT THIRTY for 10.3 and TEN POINT THREE for 10.03. How could I achieve this?

Depending of how many digits you want for identity it could be `RPADed` with 0:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 10.03 AS num FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10.30 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10.33 FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  num AS old_value,
  decode( sign( num ), -1, 'NEGATIVE ', 0, 'ZERO', NULL )
  || decode( sign( abs(num) ), +1, to_char( to_date( abs(TRUNC(num)),'J'),'JSP') )
  ||
  CASE
     WHEN INSTR (num, '.') > 0
     THEN  ' POINT ' || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TO_NUMBER (RPAD(SUBSTR(num, INSTR (num, '.') + 1)
                                                     ,2,'0')
                                                     ),'J'),'JSP')
     ELSE NULL
  END AS new_value
FROM cte;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ddb99c83c3708314c23749d7d30a3023)**

Output:

```
+-------------+------------------------+
|  OLD_VALUE  |       NEW_VALUE        |
+-------------+------------------------+
|      10.03  | TEN POINT THREE        |
|       10.3  | TEN POINT THIRTY       |
|      10.33  | TEN POINT THIRTY-THREE |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting an error:ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484
01854. 00000 -  "julian date must be between 1 and 5373484"
*Cause:    An invalid Julian date was entered.
*Action:   Enter a valid Julian date between 1 and 5373484.

Comment: I have converted your query according to my table and column like this and i get an above error: SELECT acy_avl_bal, UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(acy_avl_bal,'J'),'JSP')) || '/=' AS new_value
FROM sttm_cust_account

Comment: @user3004110 This is one limitation, number have to be INT and in range you mentioned.

Comment: I did'nt understand why you use to_date while it is a numeric column? Is this is may be the reason of error? When i remove to_date function it leads with another error.

Comment: @user3004110 This is because you want english word for numbers. Using DATE and `JSP` I can get spelled year number. Show your data.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i am in a bank and here we have billions of amount to show, and whenever i write 25000000 it gives me another error:ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string ------  Is there any straight forward query???, thanks.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda for `10.3` output is `TEN POINT THREE` but it should be `TEN POINT THIRTY` for `10.3` and `TEN POINT THREE` for `10.03`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks for the update. It's really helpful.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Any solution for numbers greater than 5373484? Because `julian date must be between 1 and 5373484`. Query fail when number is greater than 5373484.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **J --> JSP** trick:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(500,'J'),'JSP')||'/=' num_2_words FROM dual;

NUM_2_WORDS
--------------
FIVE HUNDRED/=
```

To understand how it works, look at [this explanation by Thomas Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123).