# ORA-01830 when converting number to words

Tags: sql, oracle

High value is in decimal format eg.- `100.10`, I want to convert it into word so I write below script but not getting execution by this..

```
SELECT SYMBOL, HIGH, UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIGH,'J'),'JSP'))
AMT_IN_WORDS FROM BHAV;
```

getting error of

> ORA-01830

please correct this where am wrong....

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You need to scream a little louder, we can't hear you.

Comment: I saved you from further downvotes.. Always remember, don't use all UPPERCASE while asking  questions. It is considered as shouting.

Answer (score 1):

You can creation a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION big_amt_in_words (p_input VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_running_input NUMBER;
   v_num NUMBER;
   v_amt_in_words VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   v_running_input := P_input;
   FOR i IN (
             SELECT RPAD(1, (rownum*3)+1, 0) num_value,
                    CASE LENGTH(RPAD(1, (rownum*3)+1, 0))
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'THOUSAND'
                        WHEN 7 THEN 'MILLION'
                        WHEN 10 THEN 'BILLION'
                        WHEN 13 THEN 'TRILLION'
                        WHEN 16 THEN 'QUADRILLION'
                        WHEN 19 THEN 'QUINTILLION'
                        WHEN 22 THEN 'SEXTILLION'
                        WHEN 25 THEN 'SEPTILLION'
                        WHEN 28 THEN 'OCTILLION'
                    END place_value
              FROM DUAL
           CONNECT BY rownum < 10
             ORDER BY rownum desc)
    LOOP
        v_num := TRUNC(v_running_input/i.num_value,0);
        IF v_num > 0 THEN
            v_amt_in_words := v_amt_in_words||' '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(v_num,'J'), 'JSP')||' '||i.place_value;
            v_running_input := v_running_input - (v_num * i.num_value);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    v_amt_in_words := v_amt_in_words||' '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TRUNC(v_running_input),'J'), 'JSP')
                      ||' AND '||UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((ROUND(v_running_input-TRUNC(v_running_input),2)*100),'J'),'JSP'))||' CENTS';
    RETURN TRIM(v_amt_in_words);
END;
/
```

To use it,

```
SELECT BIG_AMT_IN_WORDS(65763245345658.12) amt_in_words 
  FROM DUAL;

Output
---------------------------------------------
SIXTY-FIVE TRILLION SEVEN HUNDRED SIXTY-THREE BILLION TWO HUNDRED FORTY-FIVE MILLION THREE HUNDRED FORTY-FIVE THOUSAND SIX HUNDRED FIFTY-EIGHT AND TWELVE CENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised since the value of `high` that you have shown is a decimal, that cannot be cast as an integer implicitly, unlike 100.00. So, it cannot be converted to Julian date.

```
SELECT  UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(100.10,'J'),'JSP'))AMT_IN_WORDS FROM DUAL;
```

This causes

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

This can be resolved by rounding the decimal to the nearest integer.

```
SELECT  UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ROUND(100.10),'J'),'JSP'))AMT_IN_WORDS FROM DUAL;

| AMT_IN_WORDS |
|--------------|
|  ONE HUNDRED |
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/707)

If you really want the float component as well, although limited, you may refer this answer's EDIT2:  [How to convert number to words - ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962508/how-to-convert-number-to-words-oracle)

Comment: is there any another way for converting value & decimal value in words??

Comment: @N.kotadia : Did you refer the answer in the link I shared at the end?