# Converting number into word using length PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am converting number into word with own code using length function.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION num_to_words (NUM IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS

v_length NUMBER;
v_words VARCHAR2(100);
word_1 VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
word_1 := 'HUNDRED';
v_length := LENGTH(NUM);

IF v_length = 3
THEN v_words := SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(NUM,'J'),'JSP'),1,3) ||' '|| word_1;
END IF;

RETURN(v_words);
END;
```

Problem is when I enter "100", it successfully converts into "ONE HUNDRED".

How can I implement the code for converting "101" into "ONE HUNDRED ONE".

Answer (score 2):

The JSP conversion will do that for you; you don't need to extract the first digit, or supply the 'hundred' text yourself:

```
  IF v_length <= 3 THEN
    v_words := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(NUM,'J'),'JSP');
  END IF;
```

If you pass in 101 the result is `ONE HUNDRED ONE`. And because I changed `= 3` to `<= 3` it will work for any 1, 2 or 3-digit value, so passing in 11 returns `ELEVEN`.

For longer values you might be looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49869100/266304), which breaks the number down into groups and converts each group onto words plus the corresponding scale (e.g. 'million'). If you want non-standard grouping then it's a bit more involved, but there's a recent example for lakh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580561/266304).

Comment: I remember this came up on Ask Tom (and elsewhere) years ago. Didn't someone have a fix for putting in the missing ANDs for us Brits?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - [this response](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=spell-the-number#4209106544929) on the thread linked to from the recent quesiton tackles that, yes.