# how to display number value in words and decimals

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to display a whole number value in words in oracle

Here is the sql query i tried.
`select to_char( to_date(5373484,'J'),'Jsp') from dual;`

It Looks like the above query will not help if it is a whole number
I want to convert a whole number i.e `515.24` to words like below in oracle.
`Five hundred and fifteen and 24 cents`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to convert number to words - ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962508/how-to-convert-number-to-words-oracle)

Comment: This is a widely-available info in SO and google. You **must** do research before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example, which checks whether there are any decimals. If so, they are spelled separately.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 4432 from dual union all
  3     select 515.24 from dual
  4    ),
  5  inter as
  6    (select col,
  7            regexp_substr(col, '^\d+') fir,
  8            case when col <> round(col) then regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') end sec
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  select col,
 12    to_char(to_date(fir, 'J'), 'JSP') ||
 13    case when sec is not null then ' and ' || to_char(to_date(sec, 'J'), 'JSP') ||' cents' end spell
 14  from inter;

       COL SPELL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
      4432 FOUR THOUSAND FOUR HUNDRED THIRTY-TWO
    515,24 FIVE HUNDRED FIFTEEN and TWENTY-FOUR cents

SQL>
```